# Blurring Background image shrinks it, how to blur without it shrinking?

Tags: html, css, filter, background-image, blur

[without blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89X1a.png) . [with blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tS8H.png)
I'm a beginners for html,css. I'm trying to blur the background-images for each of my divs, but instead it shrinks it down. How do I go about blurring without it shrinking?

```css
.parallax {
  /*height: 500px;*/
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 200%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 300px;
  perspective-origin-x: 100%;
}
.parallax .title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #424242 black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* below trying to blur */

.parallax .group2 .back {
  background: #ffdfba;
  background-image: url("image/bubble.png");
  background-size:contain;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  height: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
  <div class="group group2">
          <div class="layer base">
              <div class="title">
                  Blowing Bubbles are fun! They help calm yourself and give you qualities to breath.
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="layer back">
              <div class="title">

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size: cover` for `.parallax .group2 .back`. The background image will cover the whole div area.
Hope it will help you